# Angularjs and select default value

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTML code (no, I can not to convert it in a ng-options):

```
<form>
        <div class="list">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        Price From (start)
                    </div>
                    <select required  id="priceForm" ng-model="search.priceFrom" ng-init="'search.priceFrom = searchParams.priceFrom'">
                        <option value=0>All</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="200">200</option>
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                        <option value="700">700</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        <option value="1500">1500</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000+</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        Vacation Days (start)
                    </div>
                    <select required ng-model="search.vacationDays">
                        <option value=0 >All</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10+</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
            </form>
```

I want this: 
The first time that I see this page the values of both select must be "All" (value = 0), and I think that I need only to add "required" but it does no work.

And for every next times the default value need to be the value inside searchParams.priceFrom (it is a variable in my $scope).

Where is my error ?

Thanks.

M.

Comment: Can we see you controller?

Comment: Did you try to initialize the variables `$scope.search.priceForm` and `$scope.search.vacationDays` to 0?  For the 2nd question, we would need more information about the workflow. (Is closing and reopening the browser a next time for you? Is it only in the same session? ...)

Answer (score 0):

Since both selects are bound to your `search.vacationDays` && `search.priceFrom` all you would need to do in your controller is something like:

```
$scope.search.priceFrom = 0;
$scope.search.vacationDatys = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo below

just set your serach obj in controller

```
$scope.search = {    
    priceFrom: 0,
    vacationDays: 0  

  }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.search = {

    priceFrom: 0,
    vacationDays: 0


  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <form>
      <div class="list">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Price From (start)
            </div>
            <select required id="priceForm" ng-model="search.priceFrom" ng-init="'search.priceFrom = searchParams.priceFrom'">
              <option value=0>All</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
              <option value="200">200</option>
              <option value="500">500</option>
              <option value="700">700</option>
              <option value="1000">1000</option>
              <option value="1500">1500</option>
              <option value="2000">2000+</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
              Vacation Days (start)
            </div>
            <select required ng-model="search.vacationDays">
              <option value=0>All</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```